# Scrolling RelativeLayout- white border over part of the content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a fairly simply Fragment that adds a handful of colored ImageViews to a RelativeLayout. There are more images than can fit on screen, so I implemented some custom scrolling.

However, When I scroll around, I see that there is an approximately 90dp white border overlapping part of the content right where the edges of the screen are before I scroll.
It is obvious that the ImageViews are still being created and drawn properly, but they are being covered up.

How do I get rid of this?

I have tried:

- Changing both the RelativeLayout and FrameLayout to WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, and a few combinations of those.
- Setting the padding and margins of both layouts to 0dp.

Example:
[image]

Fragment:

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener {
    int currentX;
    int currentY;
    RelativeLayout container;
    final int[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.RED, Color.BLUE};

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup fragContainer, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myfrag, null);
     }

     @Override
     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         container = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.container);
         container.setOnTouchListener(this);

         // Temp- Add a bunch of images to test scrolling
         for(int i=0; i<1500; i+=100) {
             for (int j=0; j<1500; j+=100) {
                 int color = colors[(i+j)%3];

                 ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
                 image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                 image.setBackgroundColor(color);

                 LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                 lp.setMargins(i, j, 0, 0); 
                 image.setLayoutParams(lp);

                 container.addView(image);
             }
         }
     }

    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
                currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
                container.scrollBy(currentX - x2 , currentY - y2);
                currentX = x2;
                currentY = y2;
                break;
            }   
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".FloorPlanFrag">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking through the [RelativeLayout source](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java/?v=source), I noticed that `onMeasure()` calls `applyHorizontalSizeRules(LayoutParams childParams, int myWidth)` and `applyVerticalSizeRules(LayoutParams childParams, int myHeight)`.

In `applyHorizontalSizeRules` I found that for the myWidth and myHeight params:

```
// -1 indicated a "soft requirement" in that direction. For example:        
// left=10, right=-1 means the view must start at 10, but can go as far as it wants to the right
```

The myWidth parameter is initialized to -1, and then changed based on the MeasureSpec's mode for onMeasure()'s parameters.

So I created my own View that extends RelativeLayout, and overrode onMeasure() to set the mode to 'unspecified':

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int newWidthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int newHeightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    super.onMeasure(newWidthSpec, newHeightSpec);
}
```

Works like a charm!